# Questions about using package `qasm2circ`

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib, pst-circ, circuits

The package [qasm2circ](http://www.media.mit.edu/quanta/qasm2circ/) can be find here, which is a package to draw quantum circuit. I download it and follow the file `Installation instructions`. My OS is Ubuntu. I have the following problems:

1. When I run the command `qasm2png` in the terminal in the folder `qasm2circ-v1.4`, it outputs that`qasm2png: command not found`.
2. The tex file in the folder `samples` can only be compiled from terminal with command `xelatex` but not editor. How strange! My editor is gedit with gedit-latex plugin and the configuration is
   http://t.imget.com/OriginalPicture/Soloman/geditlatexplugin.png

PS：I tried to add path but failed
http://t.imget.com/OriginalPicture/Soloman/ubuntuquestionqasm.png

Answer (score 2):

`qasm2png` is looking for `/bin/csh` to interpret the code but it seems that this does not exist on your system. This is almost certainly because you do not have `csh` installed. You can install it using Ubuntu's package manager. The package might be called something like `tcsh` rather than `csh`. (On my system `/bin/csh` is provided by `tcsh` which is an enhanced/extended version of the original `csh`.)

When you have installed it, check that it is found using `which csh`. This should return `/bin/csh`. Then try running `qasm2png` again.

To get the editor working, you either need to install things into your existing `PATH`, add the relevant directory to that `PATH` or specify the full path to relevant commands. (The last option may or may not work depending on how the scripts work exactly.)

Comment: The last option will not work.  These scripts are…poorly designed.  Props to the author for releasing the tool, but the scripts need to be worked on.  It's interesting to me that Ubuntu doesn't come packaged with `csh` though; it was my understanding that quite a few older support utilities still use it.

Comment: Thanks! `qasm2png` works but only output a dvi file not a png file, the same for `qasmpdf`.

Comment: @EdenHarder Do you have `netpbm` installed? This would be using Ubuntu's package manager - it is not a TeX thing. According to the INSTALL file, this is required to produce png files. The scripts are not doing much error checking and are not going to give you useful error messages. I'm not sure why `qasmpdf` might be failing.

Comment: @EdenHarder What am I meant to run `qasm2png` on? I can compile `test1.tex` to DVI OK. (At the terminal, anyhow.) But I'm not sure what I'm meant to apply `qasm2png` to. You said it gave you a DVI. From what? If I run it on `test1.tex`, I just get errors - nothing like a DVI. Be careful, too. It does not check to see that it is not overwriting an existing file and so will clobber your `.tex` files freely.

Comment: @cfr Thanks! `./qasm2png samples/test1.qasm` will only produce a DVI.

Comment: @EdenHarder You are doing better than me, I assure you, if you are getting a DVI. I get a syntax error complaining about line 241 of `qasm2tex.py` when I run `qasm2png` on `test1.qasm` or `test2.qasm`. (I stopped testing after this.) I tried `python2` in case the problem was python 3 but got exactly the same syntax error. I copied `test1.qasm` to the directory containing `qasm2png` but that couldn't be a problem, could it?

Comment: Could you explain how to get the editor work in details?

Comment: @EdenHarder Since I can't even get it to work on the command line and have never used `gedit`, I am really not a good person to ask, I'm afraid!

Comment: @EdenHarder You still haven't shown us how you have configured your editor to run this script. (Actually, I'm not sure whether this is even what you are trying to do. I guess `xelatex` works on normal documents?)

Comment: @cfr Thanks. The first figure in the picture is how I configure my editor. Yeah, `xelatex` works on normal documents.

Comment: @cfr The script `qasm2png` is very simple; it wants `csh` just in order to use `foreach`, that should be easy to get with standard `sh`. Programmer's laziness, as opposed to Laziness.

Comment: @egreg I didn't say anything about laziness, did I? Or Laziness, if that's different.

Comment: @cfr Uppercased “Laziness” refers to http://threevirtues.com I wanted to say that forcing `csh` for a simple script is a disputable choice; the author of `qasm2png` knows `csh` and didn't want to spend time into making the script surely compatible with any (reasonable) version of Unix, by using `sh` instead.

Comment: @egreg Oh, yes. I agree with you on that. They are, as Sean Allred said, not very well written scripts. I thought that you were saying I could avoid the problem I ran into by somehow rewriting for `sh` and I didn't understand why that would help ;).

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- Give the shell a path to work from or add the QASM directory to your `PATH` environment variable:

  ```
  $ ./qasm2png samples/test1.tex
  ```
- Your editor is incorrectly configured.  Please provide your editor and its QASM-related settings.